# pg_dump issue in docker

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Here is my [dockerfile](http://pastebin.com/4NmrbYcc) and here is my [docker-compose file](http://pastebin.com/GKXuzzEQ). When I ran `docker-compose run web rake db:migrate` I got this err

```
rake aborted!
failed to execute:
pg_dump -s -x -O -f /usr/src/app/db/structure.sql --schema=public --schema=partitioning docker_rails_dev

Please check the output above for any errors and make sure that `pg_dump` is installed in your PATH and has proper permissions.

/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:90:in `run_cmd'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:55:in `structure_dump'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:183:in `structure_dump'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:279:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:53:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:45:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:structure:dump
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

so I entered into postgres container and ran `pg_dump` and got this err

```
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] connection to database "root" failed: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

but running `pg_dump --version` gives me the version number of postgres.

any idea why this is happening?

Comment: `pg_dump --version` gives you version of pg_dump :-) If you connect into container you run as root and plain `pg_dump` command in that case tries to connect as user "root" to the database "root". You need to add parameters like -U and -d - check in documentation. Plus check pg_hba.conf file - it contains "allowances" for users to connect.

Comment: is there a way to fix the above issue?

Answer (score 3):

Using `run` command is not the best way since you need postgres server up and running. Try with `exec`, have in mind that using `-f` as argument in `pg_dump` will create a file inside the running instance so you might want to write file using `>` to redirect output and create the dump outside the container. In my case I do something like:

```
docker-compose -f $PROJECT_PATH/docker-compose-$ENV.yml exec postgres pg_dump -U $DBUSER -Z 9 $DOCKERSERVICE > backups/db/postgres-`date +"%m%d%y%H%M%S".sql.gz`
```

Where `$DOCKERSERVICE` is usually `postgres`

For you case it might be something like:

`docker-compose exec web rake db:migrate`

And a [better reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/exec/) for `docker-compose exec`

Answer (score 1):

I knew that question is old, but I stuck with the same problem:

```
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] connection to database "root" failed: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

However, I have no setup for `root` role. So the fix is `export PGUSER=postgres` for me. 
It is even possible to set `PGUSER` through `compose` file. Smth like:

```
services:
  some_exact_service:
    ...
    environment:
      PGUSER: postgres
```

Hope you understand that you may replace `postgres` role name with your own ;).